# ¿Cómo regresar al dataframe antes de aplicar aplicar la función pd.get_dummies?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe A, con tres variables categoricas `var_1, var_2, var_3`. A este dataframe lo transforma con la función `pd.get_dummies()` para obtener solo variables dummies. Mi pregunta es si existe alguna función para regresar al dataframe original. Es decir, tengo

```
import pandas as pd 
a = {'var_1': ["A1", "A2","A3"], "var_2":["B1", "B2", "B3"], "var_3":["C1","C2", "C3"], 'longitud': [19, 25, 34], "latitud": [-99, -100, -120]}
A = pd.DataFrame(data=a)

A
var_1   var_2   var_3   longitud    latitud
0   A1  B1  C1  19  -99
1   A2  B2  C2  25  -100
2   A3  B3  C3  34  -120

A_dummies=pd.get_dummies(A)
A_dummies
longitud    latitud var_1_A1    var_1_A2    var_1_A3    var_2_B1    var_2_B2    var_2_B3    var_3_C1    var_3_C2    var_3_C3
0   19  -99     1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   25  -100    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
2   34  -120    0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Quisiera aplicarle un función a A_dummies para que me retorne el dataframe A.

Nota: Puedo crear una función para realizarlo, pero me gustaría saber si ya existe algo definido como `pd.get_dummies()`. Creo que en con la librería sklearn y con la función `OneHotEncoder()` en lugar de `pd.get_dummies()` es más sencillo, pero sigo investigando.

Answer (score 0):

Pues con lo que tienes hecho,simplemente podrías llamar a `a` y así tenerlo de nuevo ya que no has sobreescrito la variable. De todas formas si por cualquier razón necesitas devolverlo de `A_dummies`, puedes hacer esto:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def reverse_dummy(df_dummies):
    pos = defaultdict(list)
    vals = defaultdict(list)

    for i, c in enumerate(df_dummies.columns):
        if "_" in c:
            k, v = c.split("_", 1)
            pos[k].append(i)
            vals[k].append(v)
        else:
            pos["_"].append(i)

    df = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Categorical.from_codes(
                              np.argmax(df_dummies.iloc[:, pos[k]].values, axis=1),
                              vals[k])
                      for k in vals})

    df[df_dummies.columns[pos["_"]]] = df_dummies.iloc[:, pos["_"]]
    return df
```